# Equivalent of Unix/Linux tail command for Powershell - that supports pipes?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, stdin, io-redirection, tail

I'm aware that Get-Content has a -Tail parameter, but as far as I can tell, there's simply no way to get it to accept piped input.

So how do I get something like this to work? I just want to be able to select first X or last X lines from any preceding command, without the hassle of creating temp files simply so I can grab the first/last lines from it.

```
# This won't work as Get-Content demands a -Path to a file
Get-Item .\* | Get-Content -Tail 10
```

Some added finagling will likely be required depending on whether the first command is providing objects or strings as output; if you can include such intermediary steps in your reply, that'd be awesome. I expect something like Out-String -stream might be the done thing?

I've scoured the internet and came up empty-handed.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried the piping the path in a ForEach-Object?
`Get-Item .\* | ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Tail 10 }`

Comment: @Grok42 Thanks for chipping in, but this is slightly askance to what I asked; see the 2 answers below my post - that is what I wanted to accomplish, and issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's pipeline is based on *objects* rather than *lines of text*, and [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76771158/45375) has the object-oriented angle covered:

- `Select-Object` `-First` / `-Last` selects only the first / last N *objects* - whatever their type - and then renders them to the display using PowerShell's rich [*for-display* output-formatting system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview).
- Given that the formatting of a single object can span *multiple* lines (consider the display output when you submit `$PSVersionTable`), there's no guarantee that the output will be limited to N *lines*.

If, by contrast, your intent is to limit the output to a given number of *display lines* - irrespective of how many *objects* the result corresponds to:

- Insert an [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) call with the `-Stream` switch parameter before the `Select-Object` call. PowerShell v5+ even has a built-in *wrapper function* for this, `oss`.
- This performs the for-display formatting to a *string*, with `-Stream` then emitting the lines of the result *one by one*.

---

A simple **example** that illustrates the two approaches and how they differ:

```bash
# Create 10 sample objects that render with Format-List
# (each property on its own line)
$objects = 
  1..10 | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ a=1*$_; b=2*$_; c=3*$_; d=4*$_; e=5*$_ } }

Write-Verbose -Verbose 'First 2 *objects*:'
# Select the first 2 *objects*, which are then rendered, 
# each with multiple lines.
$objects | Select-Object -First 2

Write-Verbose -Verbose 'First 2 *lines*:'
# Create the for-display representation as a string up front, 
# then select the first 2 *lines*
$objects | oss | Select-Object -First 2
```

This outputs the following:

```bash
VERBOSE: First 2 *objects*:

a : 1
b : 2
c : 3
d : 4
e : 5

a : 2
b : 4
c : 6
d : 8
e : 10

VERBOSE: First 2 *lines*:

a : 1
```

Note:

- PowerShell's output formatting often involves a leading and trailing *empty line*, which is why the output from the `oss`-based command starts with an empty line and only shows one property value (you could address that by eliminating blank lines as follows:
  `$objects | oss | Where-Object { $_.Trim() } | Select-Object -First 2`)
- An important use case for `oss` is quick-and-dirty *text* searches in object output via [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string):

  - E.g., the following would show only the lines that contain the digit (string) `3`:

    ```bash
    $objects | oss | Select-String '3'
    ```

    - Note that this technique is meant for convenient, *interactive* use only; for robustness, especially in *scripts*, using OO techniques for filtering, notably via [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), is the right approach.
  - Sadly, `Select-String` doesn't have the `oss` stringification logic *built in*, even though it arguably should - see [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's very nice and detailed! Didn't know about the oss wrapper, nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `Select-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to shape a piped input stream by using the `-First`/`-Last` parameters parameters, much like `head`/`tail` works in a Unix shell:

```
PS ~> 1..100 |Select-Object -First 5
1
2
3
4
5
PS ~> 1..100 |Select-Object -Last 5
96
97
98
99
100
```